# How to count elements from nested arrays (3 level) in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export interface Cars {
    items: ItemsSummary[];
}

export interface ItemsSummary{
    details: DetailsSummary[];
}

export interface DetailsSummary{
    name: string;
}
```

I have 3 level nested array. I want to get know how many `Details` belongs to `Car`
Something like this: `cars.flat(t=>t.items).flat(t=>t.details).length`

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce`:

```
let totalDetails = cars.reduce((total, car) => {
    return total += car.items.reduce((total2, item) => {
        return total2 += item.details.length;
    }, 0);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to sum up the lengths:

```
cars.reduce((s, o) => s + o.items.reduce((ss, oo)=> ss+ oo.details.length, 0), 0)
```